# How to reuse mongo client using globals, best practices

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So, I have read other topics here in StackOverflow that try to touch on this but don't have a clear solution to the problem.

First I created a config file for the mongo client which is exported from it.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const authMechanism = 'SCRAM-SHA-1';
const user = encodeURIComponent(process.env.MONGODB_USER);
const password = encodeURIComponent(process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD);
const uri = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@${process.env.MONGODB_URI}?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  loggerLevel: 'info',
});

module.exports = client;
```

From there I understand that you must have mongo client initialised once, and only once, before you listen to your application, hence I have created this index.js (entry point to the app) file that does that requiring the typical app.js where all the node config is.

```
const app = require('./app');
const db = require('../configs/db/db-config');

const port = process.env.PORT;

db.connect((err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  const database = client.db('dbnamegoeshere');
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
});
```

Now, in order for me to reuse that db anywhere I want to make queries or whatever, what is the best practice? How could I add it globally? would adding it globally affect the performance or be a bad practice?

I have seen other examples where people perform these two tasks using a class but yet again all in the same file, not with an export or a global.

One final question, where, and why should I close the db client connection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding the db connection object to the `global` object works perfectly. And if you are worried about performance, just reassign global vars to local ones.
//dbconnection.js

```
const debug = require('debug')('someapp:mongo');
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoOptions = {};
const mongoUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname";
function callback(err, r){
  debug("callback: ", err, r);
};
module.exports = function () {
  mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, mongoOptions, (err, client) => {
    if(err){
      debug("MongoDB connection error: ", err);
      throw err;
    };
    const db = global.db = client.db();
  });
};
```

And just use it like so in your root application file, once added to the file the db connection should be globally available in other files in your project.
//server.js

```
require("./dbconnection")();
const userDB = global.db.collection("Users");
userDB.find({}).toArray((err, items)=>{});
```

Comment: So then I could use global.db anywhere without requiring any extra module, is that correct?

Comment: Yes! that is correct as long as global.db is set prior.

Comment: I just noticed something, I am not familiar with this type of syntax:

const db = global.db = client.db(); does this multiple equals thing have a name so I can look it up?

Thanks for all.

Comment: That is not necessary just do ```global.db = client.db();``` instead